# On Cuda Google Vertex AI notebook, pandas dataframe.to_gbq() and pandas-gbq.to_gbq() functions write NULL records from populated dataframe to BigQuery

Tags: pandas, google-bigquery, jupyter, google-cloud-vertex-ai

Neither the pandas `dataframe.to_gbq()` function nor the `pandas-gbq to_gbq()` function write the `dataframe` to BQ - they write a table with the correct column names and number of rows, but all null values. Here's what I did:

1. Set up a Vertex AI Managed notebook with a GPU
2. Use Cuda to run my Python process on the GPU
3. Run the process (Flan-T5) to generate a set of string values
4. Write them to a dataframe
5. Examine the dataframe and verify that the values are correct and non-null
6. Use `pandas.to_gbq()` AND `pandas-gbq.to_gbq()` to write the dataframe to BQ
7. Examine the newly-created table and see that it has the correct column names and correct number of records, but only null values

Comment: can you provide a minimal example to reproduce and include versions for pandas libraries you are using?